# Avoid or format `backticks` in titles

Tags: feature-request, markdown, title

I see more and more titles with backticks in the title (like mine here)... For example: [Parse div `data` into JavaScript function (renamed by Bart meanwhile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316745/parse-div-data-into-javascript-function)

Is this a good practice? I guess not because I find this ugly, so there are three suggestions possible for me:

1. Avoid them in titles, and put a warning if the user try to use it (not an error, some user could need it some day)
2. Format titles to set a monospace font for words surronded by backticks (without changing the background-color)
3. Edit manually posts and remove backticks (see current accepted answer)

... or any other ideas if someone has a better one :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backticks in titles make no real sense. I do however not have the impression that it's big enough of an issue that we need any automatic feature to warn against it, or to prevent it from happening at all.

When you encounter it, and it really doesn't add anything to the title, just edit. At most you could leave a polite comment for the author state that such formatting does not work in titles and that they should not use it.

Comment: I guess it's the most effective workaround for the moment. Accepted.

Comment: And I "destroyed" your example doing just that. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've edited my question to avoid future confusions :)